# How should I remove the knockout for the drain in a recessed laundry box?

Tags: plumbing, washer

I am trying to set up my new washer and dryer but I am stuck. Can anyone tell me how to remove the knockout from an Oatey box?

[image]

Comment: what's a test cap? ... is it shown in the picture?

Comment: The drain pipe cover, between the hose bibbs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I recall (been a while - I used one of these boxes once and thought it was a cheesy product I'd never buy again) you either cut with a utility knife or smack with a hammer to break the plug free (hoping there's actually a drain pipe & trap properly installed, if you didn't install this yourself.)

Comment: It's a new build. I am worried that if I use a hammer it will drop into the drain hole. I will try using a utility knife. Thank you.

Comment: You can drive a screw through it to help hold onto it. Even tie a string to the screw if you like.

Comment: Having the cap fall into the drain is a real risk. I would be very carefull to avoid this. Look up videos on how to remove these.

Comment: Quick update. I used a utility knife as suggested by ecnerwal and cut it enough to insert a screw driver. I then worked my way around it with a hammer until the opening was large enough for me to pull it out completely. That worked great. Thank you for you help!

Comment: @Tropicana  Did you verify a drain pipe?

Comment: There should be a plastic bezel or rim covering the open space between the box and the drywall. Why hasn't it been installed? Usually there is a red handle for the hot water valve and blue for the cold. Why are both black here?

Comment: @JimStewart the lack of colored handles in my area would seem to indicate that is not a universal requirement.  By convention here though, hot should always be left when facing the device in question from the area it serves.

Comment: Thank you Jack and Jim Stewart. This is what it looks like now. http://imgur.com/gallery/ulCHx1O  how would I check if the drain pipe is there?

Comment: Pour  water in with a pitcher and see if it is carried away. Spillage could be confused with water leaking out from inside the wall so try not to spill.

Comment: Thank you. I'll give it a go with a squirt bottle. Is there any way I would be able to tell if it is going/not going to where it's supposed to. It's a new build in Ontario. So I am not sure what the code says about the handles either. I told the Mrs I would do it myself but she is worried about flooding. This is really making me doubt myself.

Comment: Certainly looks like you have an ABS (black) drain pipe there, so it's likely fine. Handles colored or not is not a code issue, merely a convention that some sets use, and others don't.

Comment: @JimStewart wait, are you recommending pouring water into a hole in a wall without knowing _FOR CERTAIN_ that there's something there to catch the water and carry it away?? What's wrong with just sticking a finger in the hole and feeling around? OP should either feel the smooth inside of a pipe, or should feel nothing or insulation depending on whether it's an interior or exterior wall.

Comment: Thank you Freeman. @JimStewart was probably going off the last picture I sent which shows the inside of a black ABS pipe. Also to address the missing colors, the builder forgot to put the red and blue rings which came with the Oatey box. I will proceed with the installation. I appreciate all the help, feedback and insight from all of you.